# problem replacing hardcoded with parameter values

Tags: visual-studio, ssis, sql-server-2017, biml, ssis-2017

I have this construction in my BIML file:

```
myColumns = myFile.ReadLine().Replace("\"","").Split('|');
```

I would like to replace this with:

```
myColumns = myFile.ReadLine().Replace("\"","").Split('<#=delimiter#>');
```

but apparantly that does not work. Somehow syntaxhighlighting tells me that doesn't work.....

ALSO:

```
string[] myFiles = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.csv");

string[] myFiles = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.<#=filetype#>");
```

When simply using

```
 myColumns = myFile.ReadLine().Replace("\"","").Split('delimiter');
```

it tells me `Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'char'`

delimiter is declared as `string delimiter ="|"`

when changing that to `char delimiter ="|"` I get exactly  the same error but then at the line where I am declaring delimiter.....

Comment: `char delimiter ="|";` fails because a character uses a single tick mark thus `char delimiter ='|';`

Comment: @billinkc Just a nitpick, but it uses single quotes `'` rather than either back tick ` or 'forward' tick `´` characters

Comment: @iamdave Yeah, I find when I tell people single quote, they can interpret it as one double quote `"` so I've taken to calling a single quote a tick mark and back tick as back tick. I was unaware of a forward tick, aka [acute accent](https://superuser.com/questions/254076/how-do-i-type-the-tick-and-backtick-characters-on-windows)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I am understanding you correctly, this part of your file:

```
myColumns = myFile.ReadLine().Replace("\"","").Split('|');
```

will already be contained within a code block or seperate code file, yes?  If so you do not need to parameterise the `delmiter` with another code block, but just reference the variable, assuming you have already declared it somewhere:

```
<#
...
char delimiter = '|';
...
var myColumns = myFile.ReadLine().Replace("\"","").Split(delimiter);
...
#>
```

---

In response to your comment, using this code would probably look something like this in your Biml file?

```
...
 <Tables>
  <Table Name="TableName" etc>
    <Columns>
    <# // This is the start of a Code Block

     // We can define some C# data structures
     char delimiter = '|';
     var myColumns = myFile.ReadLine().Replace("\"","").Split(delimiter);

     // Then start a loop which will generate some Biml nodes
     foreach(string col in myColumns)
     {
      // Note that the foreach loop is left open despite closing the code block on the next line.
      // This means the following Biml is looped over until the foreach ends.
    #>
     <Column Name="<#=col#>" etc />
    <# // We can then start another code block which carries on from the last one
     } // This closes the foreach loop defined earlier
    #>
    </Columns>
  </Table>
 </Tables>
...
```

You can see in this example how the C# code is contained within `<#` and `#>` tags with raw Biml everywhere else.  The use of `<#=` and `#>` tags are a syntax shortcut for referencing previously defined C# variables.  These obviously are only necessary when you are within a Biml part of the file and not already within a code block.

Comment: I guess that's how it would work with c# but these are BIML files

Comment: @Henrov  Yes, but BIML is an XML like syntax that can contain C# code *within code blocks*, as denoted by `<# ... #>` tags.  You can't just have C# anywhere within the file, it *must* be within a code block.  If you can post more of your Biml file to your question it should be pretty obvious where your Biml and C# sections start and end.

Comment: @Henrov I have added a bit more explanation on how C# works within Biml files which should help you understand how this works.

Comment: I will try this.

Comment: ery busy that is why slow response. Appreciate yo thinking with me

Comment: Error: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'char'

                    <#

                    StreamReader myFile = new StreamReader(filePath);
                     myColumns = myFile.ReadLine().Replace("\"","").Split(delimiter);

                    myFile.Close();

                    foreach(string myColumn in myColumns) 
                    {  
                    #>
I can use the delimiter parameter elsewhere

Comment: The variable `delimiter` is going to be available based on C# scoping rules. If you're in a Biml text nugget `<#= #>` or control nugget `<# #>` you'll be able to reference the variable --- just don't try to use a text nugget within a control and you'll be fine

Comment: @Henrov  The issue is right here in your error message: *Error: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'char'* - you are trying to use a `string` data type as your delimiter when the `Split` function requires a `char` data type.  In C# you can see this distinction with `char` literals using single quotes `'` and strings using double quotes `"`, as per your example code the `Replace` takes `string` data types and the `Split` a `char`: `.Replace("\"","").Split('|');`